# Issue with my TCP Service

Tags: c#, tcp

I have a C# service that creates a TCP server for receiving messages from an iPad.

It works perfectly on my lenovo without any hiccups, but when installed on my target computer, it refuses to function at all.  What could be the cause of this?

I am open to any and all ideas cause i've been trying to figure this out for a week.  Its the exact same code on two very similar platforms, but one doesn't work.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
  string programStarter = "Program Started  " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
  //Code that is supposed to create a log file in the application directory.
  ProgramLogger.logPageCreator();
  ProgramLogger.Log("Log page created/Found");
  ProgramLogger.Log(programStarter);

  //This finds the arduino port and sets current com to something other than nill
  while (ArduinoLandLine.currentCOM == null)
  {
    ArduinoLandLine.AutodetectArduinoPort();
  }
  if (ArduinoLandLine.currentCOM != null)
  {
    //Log the new found com port and send it to log file.
    ProgramLogger.Log("Arduino Found!   " + ArduinoLandLine.currentCOM);
  }
  BWTCPListener.DoWork += TCPTalker.messageScanner;
  BWTCPListener.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

That is my OnStart Code which runs perfectly every time.  Here is the TCPListener code:

```
public static void messageScanner(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  BackgroundWorker worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
  TCPResponse responseMessage = new TCPResponse();
  TcpListener server = null;
  try
  {
    Int32 port = 13000;
    IPAddress localAddress = IPAddress.Parse("The Correct IP Address");
    server = new TcpListener(localAddress, port);
    server.Start();
    Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
    string data = null;

    while (true)
    {
      Console.Write("waiting for connection.....");
      TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
      Console.WriteLine("conntected to : " + localAddress);
      data = null;
      NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
      int i;
      while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
      {
        stream.Flush();
        data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
        Console.WriteLine("Recieved: " + data);
        ProgramLogger.Log("iPad Message recieved:   " + data);
        if (data != null) Console.WriteLine(responseMessage.ToString());
        stream.Flush();
        if (data.ToString() == "1")
          ArduinoLandLine.lightsOn();
        else if (data.ToString() == "2")
          ArduinoLandLine.lightsOff();
        else if (data.ToString() == "3")
          ArduinoLandLine.blink();
        else if (data.ToString() == "4")
          ArduinoLandLine.revolve();
        else if (data.ToString() == "5")
          ArduinoLandLine.revolve2();
        else if (data.ToString() == "6")
          ArduinoLandLine.revolve3();
        else if (data.ToString() == "7")
          ArduinoLandLine.revolve4();
        else if (data.ToString() == "8")
          ArduinoLandLine.revolveFade();
        else if (data.ToString() == "9")
          ArduinoLandLine.strobe();
        else if (data.ToString() == "10")
          ArduinoLandLine.random();
        else if (data.ToString() == "11")
          ArduinoLandLine.pulse();
        else if (data.ToString() == "d")
          ArduinoLandLine.projectorScreenDown();
        else if (data.ToString() == "u")
          ArduinoLandLine.projectorScreenUp();
        worker.ReportProgress(0, responseMessage);
        stream.Flush();


        //byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        //stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
        //Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", data);
      }
      client.Close();
    }
  }
  catch (SocketException socketException)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Could not connect to server:(  SocketException: {0}", socketException);
  }
  finally
  {
    server.Stop();
  }
```

Comment: What does  `it refuses to function at all` mean?

Comment: it Initializes and runs the OnStart() method  thats it

Comment: Where is the code of `OnStart`?  what exceptions do you get?

Comment: Firewall maybe? What does your `ProgramLogger` log say?

Comment: no exceptions.. it creates the log file, finds the arduino port and message scanner isnt touched

Comment: tried the firewall first actually.  no difference was made

Comment: The code is all called and run on my lenovo, but the background worker doesnt even start 90% of the time  and that 10% it does its unresponsive

Comment: i just want to know what could cause code to work on one computer but not another

Comment: Are the same versions of Arduino DLLs installed? is the port in use for something else?

Comment: the issue is not on the arduino level of the application, it doesnt have the chance to make it that far.  The issue is with the TCPListener that refuses to respond at all

Comment: @DanielI "TCPListener that refuses to respond" makes no sense. Are you trying to say that it stays on `AcceptTcpClient`?

Comment: like the whole program just stops upon starting the server... ive logged it and nothing logs after entering the background worker

Comment: For debugging a program that operates over network, you should use Sysinternals TcpView for checking your computers network connections and HWGroup Hercules as a terminal program to simulate the opponent TCP server or TCP client or UDP endpoint. These 2 have helped me out a lot when writing network software.

Comment: Are you running the exe or from inside VS? How did you notice that the BGW is not called? You should first ensure a correct operation if the BGW, then you can go on with he networking stuff. BTW: you should make sure that OnStart() is called only once, otherwise you mess up your BGW DoWork by "over-registrating" the function call; it would get started twice or more.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure that the registration of your function to the DoWork event is wrong. See the example at MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx.

Further advices are in my comments to your question.

Answer (score 0):

it was the computers fire wall. Allowing my program access didnt work, but opening my port did

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that when a read completes you've got an entire message. TCP is not message based. You might receive a part of a message, multiple messages or really any subsection of the byte stream that TCP provides.

For example, `data.ToString() == "1"` might not match if `data == "11"`. Two message at once.